# How to pass name of parameters to aspect methods

Tags: c#, aop

Index and aspect method that used for logging below.

Action:

```
[LogAspect]
public ActionResult Index(int projectId)
{
    ...
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Aspect method:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var parameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(args.Arguments.ToList());
        string message = string.Format("Releted method parameters:{0}", parameters);
        Logger.Info(string.Format("Controller:{0}, Action:{1}", args.Method.DeclaringType.FullName, args.Method.ToString()), message);
        base.OnExit(args);
    }
}
```

I can get the value of `projectid` as integer like `[1]`.
But as you guess I am using this aspect method to log this information and it doesn't make sense if there isn't the name of the parameter (it's written to database) so I want to get the parameter like `[projectId:1]` etc.

This would be easy with reflection if I was using logger in controller but I am doing this process in aspect method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arguments` contains the values only. However, you do have the usual reflection interface in `Method`:

```
args
  .Method
  .GetParameters()
  .Select((p, i) => new { Name = p.Name, Value = args.Arguments[i] });
```

Comment: it returns null both selector and source but I got your point try to achieve this..